# Unexpected token import (url.pathToFileURL(process.env.pm_exec_path))

Tags: pm2

```
import(url.pathToFileURL(process.env.pm_exec_path))
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

This is the error. I know that there are already similar topics on this site, but they are already several years old. I tried everything, nothing helps. Maybe there is some modern solution? I'm using Debian. I'm using node v12.22.12 (npm v6.14.16), pm2@5.2.0